# Find the differences in imageview

Tags: android

Sorry for my bad writing

In the xml file i have 2 images in Linearlayout_horizontal side by side (the same image with some differences ).

I dont have any solution for know that the user click on differences or not (multi screen support and please show me in code ).

two image have just five differences . i want to know that the user click on differences or not (if the user not click on differences the health button change to brokenhealth .

the xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.alikhorshidi.whatsdiffrence.Level1" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/windsor_castle_uk" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/windsor_castle_uk2" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/health1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/health" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/health2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/health" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/health3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/health"
         />

    <View
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <View
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addtimelvl1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/addtime" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hintlvl1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hint" />
    <View
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <View
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timelvl1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00:05:00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <View
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <View
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homelvl1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/home" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backlvl1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back" />



</LinearLayout>
```

the src code

public class Level1 extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level1);

    ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    Button btn_homelvl1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homelvl1);
    btn_homelvl1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Level1.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Button btn_backlvl1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backlvl1);
    btn_backlvl1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Level1.this, MainL.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Show me your code first.

Comment: Your Question is not clear what you want to ask and what do you mean by differences. If you have 2 different imageViews then you have thier id and also their click listeners you can override click listener and perform your functionality.

Comment: Atleast try to do something then someone can help you, no one will give you whole code.

Comment: Ravi : i copy my codes .

Answer (score 1):

`OnClickListener` wont work in this case if you wish to know where the user clicked on the image. Instead use `onTouchListener` to get the x and y coordinates of the point where the user has clicked and compare it to know whether the user has clicked at the right point